# Unable to load svm model in r

Tags: r, svm

I have generated SVM model and saved it to .rds file, I used below syntax for saving

```
fit <-svm(ResolutionTime ~ ., data = complete)

retval <- list(model = fit)

saveRDS(retval, "./model.rds")
```

But when I load and tried to predict result on new data using below syntax , I am getting error

Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('svm.formula', 'svm')"

```
model <- readRDS("./model.rds")

ResolutionTimePrediction= predict(model$model,test)
```

Can anyone help me here, I tried to save model with different method like below but it is not working

```
save(model, file = "my-svm.RData")
```

Comment: It is working for me with `fit <- svm(Species ~ ., data = iris)`

Comment: @akrun, Thanks for your reply. I found what was gong wrong. I was not loading library "e1071" when prediction script was executed. once I load library "e1071" I was able to run predict

Comment: @user3734568 If you add that as an answer, it will make it easier for people to find later. You'll also be able to accept it so people know there's a solution, but you need to two days for that.